# Showing $G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, w)/ \mathbb{Q}) \simeq S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I want to show that $G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, w)/ \mathbb{Q}) \simeq S_3$, but I'm not that familiar with computing Galois groups so I don't really know how to do this exercise.

How do I approach this?

Also note that we define $w$ as: $w = \frac{1}{2}(1 + i\sqrt{3})$

Comment: @Arthur indeed.

Comment: This must probably be a duplicate.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I tried searching for it via the search function, but didn't really know what my parameters would be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is here somewhere. I'll try and give a different approach though.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Right, I don't doubt it is. I just didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

The extension $K/Q$ is Galois as its the splitting field of a seperable polynomial. The Galois group has prder 6. Notice that $\mathbf{Q}(\omega \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ are both subfields of degree three! So you have at least two subgroups of order 2. Hence the Galois group is not cyclic, hence it's $S_{3}$, $K=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$. (I am using the fact that any group of order 6 is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z}$ or $S_{3}$ and that the Galois correspondence theorem!)

Comment: I did not justify the fact that the extension has degree 6. First, we notice tht $\omega$ is imaginary and satisfy $x^{2}+x+1$ which has no roots over any real subfield (negative discriminant). Since the extension $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbf{Q}$ has degree 3 ($x^{3}-2$ is irreducible), the extension $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)/ \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) has degree 2. Hence the total extension has degree 6!

Answer (score 1):

**Affirmation:** If $p$ is a prime number and $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ of degree $p$ and $f(x)$ has exactly $2$ non-real roots then $\mathrm {Aut}_{\mathbb Q} L \simeq S_p$, where $L = \mathrm {Gal}  (f, \mathbb Q)$.

With this in mind all you need to do is showing that $f(x) = x^3 -2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ and that it has $2$ complex (non-real) roots.